# If $f(x)=(x^2+6x+9)^{50}-4x+3$ has roots $r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_{100}$, then compute $\sum_i (r_i+3)^{100}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Let $f(x)=(x^2+6x+9)^{50}-4x+3$, and let $r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_{100}$ be the roots of $f(x)$. Compute $$(r_1+3)^{100}+(r_2+3)^{100}+\cdots+(r_{100}+3)^{100}$$

How should I compute this?

Comment: What can you say about the roots of $f(x-3)$? How does $f(x-3)$ look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $r_i$ is root of the given polynomial, then $y_i = r_i + 3$ is root of the polynomial

$$f(y-3) = y^{100}-4y + 15$$

It follows

$$\sum_{i=1}^{100}y_i^{100} = 4\sum_{i=1}^{100}y_i - 100\cdot 15 = -1500$$